# How to set Tab Header Position Bottom in TabView control in xaml uwp app

Tags: c#, uwp, tabs, tabview

How do i change default header position of selected tab  to bottom. Here's my code

```
<controls:TabView x:Name="Tabs"
                  SelectionChanged="{x:Bind ViewModel.Tabs_SelectionChanged}">
                <controls:TabViewItem Header="Tab 1" FontSize="16" >
                </controls:TabViewItem>
                <controls:TabViewItem Header="Tab 2" FontSize="16">
                </controls:TabViewItem>
            </controls:TabView>
```

Also how do i get selected tag from SelectionChanged event

```
public void Tabs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var item = e.AddedItems[0] ;
            if (item != null)
            {
               
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you use Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls TabView ?

Comment: Yes. added xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"

Comment: Ok, please check the following solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to set Tab Header Position Bottom in TabView control in xaml uwp app

For your requirement, we suggest you edit [`TabView` style](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/dev/6.1.1/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/TabView/TabView.xaml#L154), and swap Tabs and  Footer positions.

Copy above style into your app.xaml file and find `ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"` and modify  `Grid.Row="1"` to `Grid.Row="3"` then find

```
   <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
                  Content="{TemplateBinding Footer}"
                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding FooterTemplate}" />
```

modify  `Grid.Row="3"` to `Grid.Row="1"`. Now the tabs will be placed on bottom.

**Update**

Ok, I got it, you could edit `TabViewItemHeaderTemplate` control template and find `Rectangle x:Name="SelectionIndicator"` and change default `VerticalAlignment` as Bottom. Please copy below style to your app.xaml file.

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="TabViewItemHeaderTemplate"
                         TargetType="comm:TabViewItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
                  ex:FrameworkElementExtensions.AncestorType="local:CustomTabView"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                  FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}"
                  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="LayoutRootScale" />
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionIndicator"
                           Height="2"
                           Margin="0,1"
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                           Fill="{ThemeResource TabViewSelectionIndicatorForeground}"
                           Opacity="0" />
    
                        <Grid Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <Grid x:Name="ContentPresenterGrid">
                                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <!--  Modifications of default ListViewItem Template for our Tab Here  -->
                                <Viewbox x:Name="IconBox"
                                 MaxWidth="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderIconSize}"
                                 MaxHeight="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderIconSize}"
                                 Margin="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderIconMargin}"
                                 Visibility="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource NullVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}"
                                              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                                </Viewbox>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                          Grid.Column="1"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                          FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                                          OpticalMarginAlignment="TrimSideBearings" />
                                <!--  Use grid to toggle visibility based on IsClosable property and inner border for hover animations.  -->
                                <Border x:Name="CloseButtonContainer"
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Width="{Binding (ex:FrameworkElementExtensions.Ancestor).IsCloseButtonOverlay, Converter={StaticResource CloseCollapsingSizeConverter}, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                Visibility="{Binding IsClosable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                    <Border x:Name="CloseButtonBorder"
                                    Width="{StaticResource TabViewItemHeaderCloseWidth}"
                                    Margin="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderCloseMargin}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    Visibility="Collapsed">
                                        <Button x:Name="CloseButton"
                                        x:Uid="/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/Resources/WindowsCommunityToolkit_TabView_CloseButton"
                                        Style="{StaticResource TabViewItemCloseButtonStyle}">
                                            &#xE711;
                                        </Button>
                                    </Border>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
    
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Icon.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
    
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!--  Close Button  -->
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CloseButtonBorder"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CloseButtonBorder"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                            Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Icon.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="SelectionIndicator.Opacity" Value="0.4" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderBackgroundSelected}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Icon.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderForegroundSelected}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderForegroundSelected}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
    
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!--  Selected Bar  -->
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionIndicator"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 To="1"
                                                 Duration="0" />
    
                                        <!--  Close Button  -->
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CloseButtonBorder"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CloseButtonBorder"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                            Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOverSelected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Icon.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
    
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!--  Selected Bar  -->
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionIndicator"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 To="1"
                                                 Duration="0" />
    
                                        <!--  Close Button  -->
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CloseButtonBorder"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CloseButtonBorder"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                            Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="PressedSelected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="LayoutRoot.Background" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderBackgroundSelected}" />
                                        <Setter Target="Icon.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderForegroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderForegroundPressed}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
    
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <!--  Selected Bar  -->
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionIndicator"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 To="1"
                                                 Duration="0" />
    
                                        <!--  Close Button  -->
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CloseButtonBorder"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                            Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CloseButtonBorder"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                            Value="Visible" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
    
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Enabled" />
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Icon.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
    
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable" />
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
    
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint" />
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Bottom"
                                                        ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                                        TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Top"
                                                        ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                                        TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Right"
                                                        ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                                        TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Left"
                                                        ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}"
                                                        TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
    
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"
                                              To="NoReorderHint" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
    
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DragStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="NotDragging" />
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="Dragging">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDragThemeOpacity}"
                                                 Duration="0" />
                                        <DragItemThemeAnimation TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="DraggingTarget" />
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingPrimary" />
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultipleDraggingSecondary" />
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="DraggedPlaceholder" />
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="Reordering">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderThemeOpacity}"
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.240" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReorderingTarget">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                 To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderTargetThemeOpacity}"
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.240" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRootScale"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                                 To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderTargetThemeScale}"
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.240" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRootScale"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                                                 To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderTargetThemeScale}"
                                                 Duration="0:0:0.240" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="MultipleReorderingPrimary" />
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="ReorderedPlaceholder">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
    
                                <VisualState x:Name="DragOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation TargetName="LayoutRoot" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
    
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"
                                              To="NotDragging" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
    <!--  Based on Style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListViewItem  -->
    <Style TargetType="comm:TabViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderRevealBorderBrush}" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderBorderThickness}" />
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderBackground}" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderForeground}" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderMargin}" />
                    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
                    <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="14,0" />
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderMinWidth}" />
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderMinHeight}" />
                    <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TabViewItemHeaderMaxWidth}" />
                    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="IsClosable" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource TabViewItemHeaderTemplate}" />
                </Style>
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried your solution but its still showing on top

Comment: Sorry i think you have misunderstood. I have to just change that selected line from top to bottom as i have added in image

Comment: I have update the case reply, and if the answer is solved your problem please consider mark it.

Comment: Hi, i have copied your style exactly but changing VerticalAlignment as Bottom for SelectionIndicator is not working. Have you made any other changes ?

Comment: it looks you have not add tabview.xaml resource into your project. please check this [line](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/TableViewTest/blob/master/TableViewTest/App.xaml#L12).